# Best practice to create variations of an app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, software-design

I've got an application with news, products, printed issues and some other smaller objects which is live and working well.

Now I would like to use this app for two or three other websites that have different content, CSS, views and even some logic needs to be adjusted. What is now the best practice to go for?

What I came up with so far:

- Branches: `master` which stays untouched. `Website1`, `website2` and `website3` branched off with respective changes.
- Forks: Fork the base app and create 3 more repositories with the changes.
- Engine: Turn app into some kind of Engine or alike, mount it in a new app and override everything there.
- Keep everything as as and create some configuration file to enable/disable features etc.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!